# Ubuntu Linux: Netbeans cannot detect Git or Cordova installed

Tags: linux, git, cordova, netbeans

Following [guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted.html), I installed every needed package and they're apparently all working fine

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin:/home/maxxer/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ node -v
v0.10.33
$ cordova --version
hello: 
4.1.2
$ git --version
git version 2.1.0

$ which node
/usr/bin/node
$ which cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

Yet when I try creating a new HTML5 Cordova app NB says I'm missing git or cordova installation... I found several bugs on NB bugzilla, but none of them apply here.

Forgot to say I'm using NetBeans 8.0.1 on amd64.

Comment: Where do you define ```$PATH``` ? More specifically, where do you put ```/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin``` to the ```$PATH``` ?

Comment: ~/.profile. That was theoretically unnecessary, since there's a cordova symlink in /usr/local/bin

Comment: And if you go to Help->Check for updates in NetBeans, does it show anything?

Comment: no update, in fact I have automatic update check enabled...

Comment: Ok, The output from ```cordova --version``` really contains the "hello:” ? Also you might check IDE log (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile ) in moment you see the message mentioned in title. There could be something relevant

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I checked log files but sadly there's no evidence of the reason why it's failing. The command really contains "hello:", I'll investigate further on that, indeed looked strange to me too! apparently every `cordova` command I launch outputs "hello:" as first line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ladar for helping me out I found out that the culprit was indeed that **hello:** printed by any `cordova` command (like `cordova --version` or `cordova --help`). I don't know why this originally existed, since I installed cordova using `npm install -g cordova`, and even running `update` the output was always the same.

So I searched cordova executable with

```
which cordova
```

and around line 20:

```
// Set this to 1 to enable timestamp collection via addTs().
console.log('hello: ');
if (0) {
    var ts = [];
```

Adding `//` in front of the `console.log` finally made Netbeans work!

Thanks again @ladar for your suggestions

Comment: Glad it works. NetBeans expects output from ```cordova -version``` to be in form of X.Y.Z (or X.Y.Z-A.B.C for older Cordova). I wonder where this console output comes from, I don't have it with 4.1.2...